# Android: Issue with hiding title bar

Tags: android, android-manifest, titlebar, android-titlebar

I want to hide the title bar in all activities of my app. To do that, I put the following attribute in the  tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

The title bar is now hidden, but **my problem is** that my app looks weird with that attribute.

Before:

http://imageshack.us/a/img831/6905/screenshot1355296053406.png

with the noTitleBar attribute:

http://imageshack.us/a/img211/581/screenshot1355295921669.png

It looks like there is less contrast..

It makes no difference if the `noTitleBar` attribute is in the application tag or in each activity tag.

Hope you can help me with my problem.

Comment: have you tried as : `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); `?

Answer (score 4):

In `onCreate()` of activity write following:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you have also removed the Theme of your application together with the title bar.

I'm not sure what your theme was before, but you should extend an existing theme. Something like this in your styles file:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.">

</style>
```

Maybe your parent theme should be `android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`?

Comment: Thanks! This solved this odd graphical issue I was experiencing!

Answer (score 0):

You've accepted no answer so I'm going to toss my 2 cents in here:

Adding this snippet of code might be helpful:

```
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```